# Tips to manually focus sharply with viewfinder?

Tags: focus, manual-focus, tips

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one get manual focus right with a fast-aperture lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2297/how-does-one-get-manual-focus-right-with-a-fast-aperture-lens)

I feel difficult to manually focus via the view finder because of its small size.Its seems to be in good focus while viewing through viewfinder but its actually not.
Any tips on making sharp focus viewing through viewfinder?